# How to analyze a data set directly from website without first downloading it?

Tags: data-analysis

I am learning Analysing data for my research. There is a website that contains all the data set for every day for the past 26 years. I have to write a python code such that if I enter the date, the data set for that day should open. Since the files are in .cdf format I have to use python to open them. Can someone tell me what are the things that I need to learn and what are the libraries that will help me to open the data set from the website without first downloading them? I have some experience with python but not a lot.
Also is there any good source that I can visit to learn more about Data Analysis using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/) for this matter.

Pandas lets you store files on a dataframe using a link, without downloading it to your local machine.

Comment: This is not a useful answer, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer